# site map generators cant identify angular redirected URLs

Tags: angularjs, search-engine, sitemap

First of all i am angular noob.
I have a blog(http://naren.me) hosted in appengine and am using angularjs.

When i search "naren.me is python" in google, I see search result showing "Loding..." text, the text which is supposed to be displayed before ng-view loads.

[image]

When i generate sitemap for my site i don't see any angular redirected URLs at all.
Am i missing something ?
Here is the angular app.js file of my site.
https://github.com/Narengowda/naren.me/blob/master/static/angularBlogFiles/js/app.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google bot and other cralwers can't execute javascript, they will request your page and just index whatever is there in the html.
You can read more about it here [Google's Crawler Guidelines](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/ajax-crawling/)

What you have to do is provide to Google and other search engines a static version of your website

You have some alternatives to solve this problem.

**Paid service**

This is the easiest way to generate and serve google with a static version of your website, here are some providers **prerender.io**, **Brombone**, **seo4ajax**, you can google for more providers.

Some of them have a free plan that would fit your needs better.

**Make your own service to generate static web pages**

You can build your own solution to generate your static pages [learn here](http://www.yearofmoo.com/2012/11/angularjs-and-seo.html).

Answer (score 1):

The new way of doing this is to include in your angular.module('app').config function. (usually app.js)

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!');
```

Then in your index.html you'll want

```
<base href="/#!">
<meta name="fragment" content="!" />
```

between your  tags.

finally, you'll need to edit  your .htaccess (apache) with something like:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
IndexIgnore */*

RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^app/(.*) /app/#/$1 [NC,L]
```